# Match pair of cells with another pair of cells

Tags: excel, match

I was trying to return a TRUE or FALSE value (to be used for conditional highlighting) to see if a pair of cells match another pair of cells (important that it's a pair or, more accurately, on the same row). For instance, what formula would be appropriate for the following desired output to be reflected.

[image]

Note that here we are checking if Column 3 and 4 values together appear in column 1 and 2 together.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and which specific part did you get stuck on? If you break the problem down into steps and try each step desperately you should be able to get most of the way there. Start by working out how to check for a match in a range of cells, note that you can use a vlookup to get the row number, and use that number to work out of the adjacent cell in column 2 matches do using an `IF` and `AND` logical checks to show TRUE or FALSE

Comment: @sorifiend I tried something like this. =NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(CONCAT(D2:E2),CONCAT($A$2:$B$6),0))) I tried to concat column 3 and 4 value together and see if it matched a concat'd value on Column 1 and 2. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data this should work:

`=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,D2:E2),TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,$A$2:$B$6))))`

This will not work if you can have "Apple|A" and "A|Apple".